# Can there be a fictitious centripetal force?

Tags: acceleration, inertial-frames, rotation, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Can their be a radially inward inertial force? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force is says nothing on Wikipedia about this.

Comment: What situation were you thinking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. What path does a stationary object follow when it's viewed by somebody who is in a rotating reference frame (for example, on a merry-go-round)? It follows a circle, right? Well, objects that are moving in a circle are acting under a centripetal force. What's more, the person in that rotating frame sees everything being under a [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force), so the centripetal force has to not only be large enough to make the object move in a circle, it has to counteract the centrifugal force. What supplies the centripetal force is the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force). The Coriolis force doesn't always provide a centripetal force, because it is velocity dependent, but in this case it does.

Any inertial observer will say the object isn't accelerating, though, so the "forces" that the rotating observer attributes to controlling its motion are described as fictitious.

Comment: Yes. thank you. I was confused as to whether a centripetal force that is usually defined on the internet as a real force, could not be in some cases. The coriolis force is velocity dependent but could their be a non velocity dependent case?

Comment: In your example, the inertial force does not point radially inward.  It is the conventional outward-pointing centrifugal force.  The force that points in to the center of the merry-go-round is not an inertial force.

Comment: @shawnny321 No. The Coriolis force is always velocity dependent, and the centrifugal fictitious force is always velocity independent. There's only one more fictitious force that I know of, and that's the same "force" you experience on an accelerating elevator.

Comment: @pwf in order to move in a circle with uniform velocity the net force has to be centripetal with magntude $mv^2/R$. If the Coriolis force, a fictitious force, isn't supplying the centripetal force, and counteracting the centrifugal force,  in my example, what is?

Comment: The centripetal force is from whatever is holding the observer on the merry-go-round, e.g. friction, the force from a pole the person is holding onto, etc.

Comment: @pwf You've misunderstood my example. The person on the merry-go-round is observing something that is stationary to someone not on it, and describing the "forces" acting on the stationary object.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, I guess that works.

Comment: From Sean's answer I would consider this question done.

Answer (score -1):

The term "centripetal" (center seeking) force comes from Newton. Picture a stone at the end of a sling being whirled around. Newton's law 1 says an object in a state of motion stays in that state of motion in a straight line unless acted on by an outside force. Law 2 says the outside force causes a change in the direction of motion. The stone would be moving in a straight line except that there is a force directed toward the center that causes the stone to deviate from the straight line.

So, whenever there is a center of some kind, and a mass moves about it in some kind of orbit, then centripetal force is said to be acting on the object.

Answer (score -1):

An inertial (a.k.a. fictitious) force in an accelerating frame corresponds to the opposite of the acceleration of that frame relative to an inertial frame.  A radially-inward (centripetal) inertial force would occur in any reference frame that was accelerating radially outward in an inertial frame.  For example:  an observer in a rocket ship accelerating away from the center of the earth (either moving away from the earth and speeding up or coming towards the earth and slowing down) would experience an inertial force towards the center of the earth.

Comment: A rocket is a good example. But in this case are there any coriolis forces?

Comment: No, but you didn't ask about coriolis forces, only centripetal inertial forces.

Comment: Ah. Yes. sorry there